# SQL Server : if one value in a column occurs at least once or another value more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, having

I'm glad I have a question with at least a working example this time. This used to be an efficient query when I was just had criteria where an result was returned if it had a count >= 1. Then I had to an additional count for different code values and if they occur 2 or more times. The query went from running in a few seconds to about 43 seconds.

I think I have the logic right but I was wondering if someone had a more efficient way to do this.

```
select person.person_id
from person
where 
person.person_id in (
        select procedure.person_id
        from procedure
        where
        procedure.performed_by = '555555'
        and procedure.code in (
                '99201', '99202'
                )
        and year(procedure.service_date) = year(getdate())
        group by procedure.person_id
        having count(1) >= '1'
        ) -- having count >= 1 occurrences
or person.person_id in (
        select person_id
        from procedure
        where
        procedure.performed_by = '55555'
        and code in (
                '99304','99305'
                )
        and year(procedure.service_date) = year(getdate())
        group by procedure.person_id
        having count(1) >= '2'
        ) -- having count >= 2 occurrences
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits, @marc_s!  I was wanting to make it as searchable as possible.  this is the best source for sql info and I didn't want to limit it to one database because it's pretty universal.

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and the expected result based on such sample or, even better, create `SQL Fiddle` [sqlfidle.com]. It seems that your query can and should be streamlined.

Comment: I'm still getting the hang of stackoverflow and I'll start using SQL Fiddle as it definitely does help.  Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this speed it up?

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    select procedure.person_id
    from procedure
    where
    procedure.performed_by = '555555'
    and procedure.code in ( '99201', '99202' )
    and year(procedure.service_date) = year(getdate())
    group by procedure.person_id
    having count(1) >= '1'

    UNION

    select person_id
    from procedure
    where
    procedure.performed_by = '55555'
    and code in ('99304','99305')
    and year(procedure.service_date) = year(getdate())
    group by procedure.person_id
    having count(1) >= '2'
)

select person.person_id
from person 
JOIN CTE ON CTE.Person_id = Person.Person_Id
```

Comment: holy carp!  That union brought it down to about 1 second.  I really need to learn to use those.  I combined both of your fixes to clean it up and speed it up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your first `IN` is just checking for existance, so there is no real need of using `HAVING` (on another note, why are you comparing `COUNT(1)` with a string?, the result is an `INT`, so you should use `>=1` or `>=2` instead). You are also using a function on `service_date` before comparing it, you shouldn't do that since unables the use of a possible index on that column. 
I would write your query this way:

```
select p.person_id
from person p
where exists (  select 1
                from procedure
                where
                procedure.performed_by = '555555'
                and procedure.code in ('99201', '99202')
                and procedure.service_date >= dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,getdate()),0)
                and procedure.service_date < dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,getdate())+1,0)
                and procedure.person_id = p.person_id)
or person.person_id in (
        select person_id
        from procedure
        where
        procedure.performed_by = '55555'
        and code in ('99304','99305')
        and procedure.service_date >= dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,getdate()),0)
        and procedure.service_date < dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,getdate())+1,0)
        group by procedure.person_id
        having count(1) >= 2
        ) -- having count >= 2 occurrences
```

Comment: thank you for helping me clean up my query.  It's shaved a few seconds off getting rid of that 1st count.  It's a huge table and there are a bunch more codes in the in() statements but for brevity I just wanted to show there was more than one.  I think the speed is unavoidable with the second counting that has to happen.